# How to determine cause for failure of fwrite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, fwrite, stdio, errno

I'm trying to determine cause of an fwrite failure.

I want to handle different cases for the error:

- No memory,
- No permission, etc

In some platforms we can use **errno** to determine the error for failure.

*Is there anything similar that can be used for iOS? Or can errno itself be used in iOS?*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use fwrite instead of using the NSData or NSString classes? They will give you very precise errors if you have a read or write fail.

Comment: This was an old implementation. I wanted to know if there is a way to handle it. 

This is a wrapper function to a c library and so the data was not in NSData format

Comment: There are some places where I can't replace fwrite with NSData's writeToFile